# Searching multiple index with different fields

Tags: elasticsearch

We are using ES and getting response properly for 1 index with search fields. I need suggestions of following :
Problem : I have different objects like contact, account have records which is searchable by in account (name field will be used to search) where in contact (Email, phone field will be used to search)

1. Should I use 1 index and keep contact and account in same index with different type (account, contact) to separate the records.
2. Should I create 2 index, 1 for account and another for contact.
   Whatever is preferrable, please give me search tips. How it will search based on different fields.

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my answer that I found on official website.

1. It is preferable to have separate index for each types (Account, Contact) etc.
2. Use below kind of search json to search among all the indexes.

`{"index" : "contacts"}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}}
{"index" : "accounts"}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}}`

curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XGET localhost:9200/_msearch --data-binary "@requests"; echo

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should know your use case. Suppose There is lots of search queries are going to come which going to access both information like account and contact info, Then i would suggest to make one index. It will help you to perform complex queries like aggregation etc.

It will also help you to select multiple fields from account as well as contact info.

If query is going to totally isolated, Then you should go for different dedicated indices. You can simply mention multiple index name by comma separated [check this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html)

Example:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/account,contact/_search?pretty' -H 'application/json' -d'
{
    "query":{
        "name":"foo"
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case 1 account could have multiple contacts so better to have account and contacts in separate index. 
Elasticsearch supports multi index search that can be utilize to execute search on multiple indexes.